# Is 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' obsolete for .net core 3.1? Then which package to use instead?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am starting a new project in **ASP.NET Core 3.1**. In the model project they used these *3 packages* in **project_name.json** file:

> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools ": { "version":
>   "1.0.0-preview2-final", "type": "build" },
>
> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
>
> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1"

And there was a **tools** section in **project_name.json file**:

> "tools": { "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools":
>   "1.0.0-preview2-final", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools":
>   "1.0.0-preview2-final"}

which adds *' "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final" '*.

I want to install the packages from **NuGet package manager** simply. But I am not finding:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools

package there. I looked out what's its replacement but didn't come up with one.

And, there was a package *'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core'* that I replaced for *' "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1" '.*

### So, the questions are,

1. What is the replacement for *'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools'*? Is the package like *'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor'* in **NuGet** the replacement? Or should I add it manually in **.csproj**? If 'yes' then I think that the package is a little outdated as it last was updated in 2016. And, can I do that manually in **.csproj** as I can do in **project_name.json**?
2. How to configure the **tools** section? As there are no tools section now in the **.csproj** file like **project_name.json** file has.
3. Is *'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core'* is replacment for *'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc'*?

***Thank you***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the replacement for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools'? Is the
>   package like 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor' in NuGet the replacement? Or
>   should I add it manually in .csproj? If 'yes' then I think that the
>   package is a little outdated as it last was updated in 2016. And, can
>   I do that manually in .csproj as I can do in project_name.json?

**Actually**, the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools/1.1.0-preview4-final) exists under `nuget.org` and it is just a preview version.

In **Nuget package management UI**, it has a set switch to separate the official and preview nuget packages.

You can refer to this:

[image]

Besides, you can add reference node directly in `xxx.csproj` file. The UI function is just download the related nuget package into the local and then modify `xxx.csproj` to add the **Reference** elements.

Add like these in your `xxx.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>   
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" Version="1.0.0-preview2-final" />    
</ItemGroup>
```

> How to configure the tools section? As there are no tools section now
>   in the .csproj file like project_name.json file has.

So far, the latest Net Core does not support [project.json format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/archive/project-json#projectlockjson).Instead, they migrate it into `xxx.csproj` file.

So in the new Net Core 3.1 project, you should change `xxx.csproj` to add them.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#tools) shows how to migrate each node in `project.json` file to `xxx.csproj` file.

About tools section, you can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#tools), use `DotNetCliToolReference` selection in `xxx.csproj` file.

**Solution**

For your issue, you should add like this in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-preview2-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then you can use it.

> Is 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' is replacment for
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc'?

They are quite different from each other. Each has its own feature.

Comment: What's a 'Pre-release versions' package?

Comment: It refers to the priority introduction of the user experience, based on the user experience constantly improve the nuget package features. To a certain extent, the author will synthesize all the points in the launch of the final release version. All of these are up to the author.

Comment: after fixing all the issue they gave me   _'RAZOR SDK1006 Detected Razor language version downgrade. This is typically caused by a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design package. Consider removing this package reference'_  warning at last. The part of the project I am solving is slimier to this: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6BW6pg2Mkg&list=PL2Q8rFbm-4ruplp2SRUTQjZaFfxh-knS0&index=5). Should I install 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design'?

Comment: For this issue, you can refer to [this similar github issue](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/cslaforum/issues/823).